# Error: The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, MenuInfo, Widget?)'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Consumer<MenuInfo> buildMenuMethod(MenuInfo currentMenuInfo) {
    return Consumer<MenuInfo>(
      builder:(Widget child, MenuInfo value,BuildContext context),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
        child: TextButton(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: currentMenuInfo.title == '    Clock    '
                ? Colors.grey.shade900
                : Colors.transparent,),
```

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/WMp5FnQ1X_g?list=PL3wGb9_yWsvKfjFgXntI_uxUV7R0L0Act&t=611) youtube tutorial but it is old so I can full fill it

[This](https://github.com/MrCrazyVampire/clockey) is my full code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line and see if it helps.

```
      builder:(BuildContext context, MenuInfo value, Widget? child) {},
```

Your builder function is missing the curly braces at the end.

Comment: The argument type 'Widget Function(Widget, MenuInfo, BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, MenuInfo, Widget?)'

Comment: Well then you should rearrange it as such. Just press ctrl+space after builder: and let the IDE create it for you actually. I edited the answer with something that may work.

Comment: builder: (context, value, child) {}
it created this
should i add the Build context menuInfo and widget?

Comment: `builder: (BuildContext context, MenuInfo value,Widget child) {},`
i did this and it threw the error
      `The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, MenuInfo, Widget)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, MenuInfo, Widget?)'`

Comment: I think it was a dart null safety issue I addedd a ? after wiget